# how to find which row values are not changing a lot within a threshold

Tags: r

I have a data which looks like below

```
df<-structure(list(C1 = c(0.003926348, 0.001642442, 6.72e-05, 0.000314789, 
0.00031372, 0.000196342, 0.01318432, 8.86e-05, 0.005671017, 0.003616196, 
0.026635645, 0.001136402, 0.000161111, 0.005777738, 0.000145104, 
0.000996546, 4.27e-05, 0.000114159, 0.001152384, 0.002860251, 
0.000284873), C2 = c(0.003901373, 0.001526195, 6.3e-05, 0.000387266, 
0.000312458, 0.000256647, 0.012489205, 0.00013071, 0.005196136, 
0.003059834, 0.024624562, 0.001025486, 0.000144964, 0.005659078, 
0.000105755, 0.000844871, 5.88e-05, 0.000118831, 0.000999354, 
0.002153167, 0.000214486), T1 = c(0.003646894, 0.001484503, 4.93e-05, 
0.00036715, 0.000333378, 0.000244199, 0.010286787, 6.48e-05, 
0.006180042, 0.00387491, 0.025428464, 0.001075376, 0.000122088, 
0.005448152, 0.000103301, 0.000974826, 4.32e-05, 0.000109876, 
0.001030364, 0.002777244, 0.000221169), T2 = c(0.00050388, 0.001135969, 
0.000113829, 2.14e-06, 0.00010293, 0.000315704, 0.01160593, 8.46e-05, 
0.004495437, 0.003062559, 0.018662663, 0.002096675, 0.000214814, 
0.002177849, 8.61e-05, 0.001057254, 3.27e-05, 0.000115822, 0.008133257, 
0.021657018, 0.000261339), G1 = c(0.001496712, 0.001640965, 0.000129124, 
3.02e-06, 0.000122839, 0.000305686, 0.01378774, 0.000199637, 
0.00534668, 0.00300097, 0.023290941, 0.002595433, 0.000262479, 
0.002926346, 0.000125655, 0.001302624, 4.89e-05, 0.000122862, 
0.009851791, 0.017621282, 0.000197561), G2 = c(0.00114337, 0.001285636, 
0.000122848, 2.46e-06, 9.1e-05, 0.000288897, 0.012288087, 0.000122286, 
0.002575368, 0.002158011, 0.022008677, 0.002017026, 0.000241754, 
0.003340175, 0.00013424, 0.001517655, 4.78e-05, 0.000110353, 
0.008293286, 0.018999466, 0.000191129)), .Names = c("C1", "C2", 
"T1", "T2", "G1", "G2"), row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
"F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "PP", 
"TT", "EE", "FF", "AS"), class = "data.frame")
```

what I want to know is to find those rows that are higher or lower than average of the first two columns (row-wise)
for example

```
   C1     C2    C3   C4
    A 1.2   1.3   1.6   1.9  
    B 1.2   1.0   0.1   0.2

Average 1.2 +1.3 =1.25
Average 1.6 +1.9 =1.75
```

It means the A is true because the average of the first two row values are 0.5 different than the average of the second two values on the same row

The same for the B

```
Average 1.2 +1.0 =1.1
Average 0.1   0.2 = 0.15
```

It means that the B is also true

I just want to compare each two columns based on the first two columns (in above data we have 3 columns) so we will have for the first two columns (1 and 2) versus column (3 and 4) and first two column (1 and 2) versus the last two pairs (5 and 6)

Comment: Nevermind, just saw the *change a lot* part... what do you mean *a lot*?

Comment: @Sotos for example with a threshold of 0.5 as it is shown in my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
df$A <- with(df, (C1 + C2) / 2 - (T1 + T2) / 2 > 0.5)
df$B <- with(df, (C1 + C2) / 2 - (G1 + G2) / 2 > 0.5)
```

Out:

```
> df
            C1          C2          T1          T2          G1          G2     A     B
A  0.003926348 0.003901373 0.003646894 0.000503880 0.001496712 0.001143370 FALSE FALSE
B  0.001642442 0.001526195 0.001484503 0.001135969 0.001640965 0.001285636 FALSE FALSE
C  0.000067200 0.000063000 0.000049300 0.000113829 0.000129124 0.000122848 FALSE FALSE
D  0.000314789 0.000387266 0.000367150 0.000002140 0.000003020 0.000002460 FALSE FALSE
E  0.000313720 0.000312458 0.000333378 0.000102930 0.000122839 0.000091000 FALSE FALSE
F  0.000196342 0.000256647 0.000244199 0.000315704 0.000305686 0.000288897 FALSE FALSE
G  0.013184320 0.012489205 0.010286787 0.011605930 0.013787740 0.012288087 FALSE FALSE
H  0.000088600 0.000130710 0.000064800 0.000084600 0.000199637 0.000122286 FALSE FALSE
I  0.005671017 0.005196136 0.006180042 0.004495437 0.005346680 0.002575368 FALSE FALSE
J  0.003616196 0.003059834 0.003874910 0.003062559 0.003000970 0.002158011 FALSE FALSE
K  0.026635645 0.024624562 0.025428464 0.018662663 0.023290941 0.022008677 FALSE FALSE
L  0.001136402 0.001025486 0.001075376 0.002096675 0.002595433 0.002017026 FALSE FALSE
M  0.000161111 0.000144964 0.000122088 0.000214814 0.000262479 0.000241754 FALSE FALSE
N  0.005777738 0.005659078 0.005448152 0.002177849 0.002926346 0.003340175 FALSE FALSE
O  0.000145104 0.000105755 0.000103301 0.000086100 0.000125655 0.000134240 FALSE FALSE
P  0.000996546 0.000844871 0.000974826 0.001057254 0.001302624 0.001517655 FALSE FALSE
PP 0.000042700 0.000058800 0.000043200 0.000032700 0.000048900 0.000047800 FALSE FALSE
TT 0.000114159 0.000118831 0.000109876 0.000115822 0.000122862 0.000110353 FALSE FALSE
EE 0.001152384 0.000999354 0.001030364 0.008133257 0.009851791 0.008293286 FALSE FALSE
FF 0.002860251 0.002153167 0.002777244 0.021657018 0.017621282 0.018999466 FALSE FALSE
AS 0.000284873 0.000214486 0.000221169 0.000261339 0.000197561 0.000191129 FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: thanks is it possible to make a threshold of 0.5 for example?

Comment: Yeah it is. It would be something like: `with(df, (C1 + C2) / 2 - (T1 - T2) / 2 > 0.5)`

Comment: how is it making the average differences ? `C1 + C2 - T1 - T2 > 0.5` ? do you know also a way to show it visually ?

Comment: You would need the division by 2 as per my comment above to check the difference of means. I am not sure what you want to visualize here. The differences or the TRUE/FALSE? Check `?plot`

Comment: both are ok, the differences and true and false. I would definitely accept and like your answer

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: thanks, if you ever could make a plot too :-) thanks again

Comment: Np, A start could be `plot(df$A)`. Feel free to ask a separate question for this one if `plot(df$A)` is not what you are looking for, as we would want questions to be separated.

Comment: thanks it is already good, I will try to search a bit and if I find difficulty I will ask again